# Multiprocessing Return Multiple Values

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to use Multiprocessing.Process to compute a function that takes in two arguments and return two values. As a simplified example, I have tried using the following code

```
import multiprocessing

# function to loop over
def my_func(x,y):
    return x+y, x-y

# worker function
def worker(procnum_1, procnum_2, x, y, return_dict):
    print("procnum_1: "+str(procnum_1)+", procnum_2: "+str(procnum_2))
    return_dict[procnum_1][procnum_2] = my_func(x[procnum_1],y[procnum_2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # lists to apply the function to
    x_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    y_list = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17]

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(len(x_list)):
        for j in range(len(y_list)):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,j,x_list,y_list,return_dict))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    # print the result
    print(return_dict.values())
```

However, this function return an empty array [ ]. Moreover, the code does not print the line inside the worker function. I am aware of [How to retrieve multiple values returned of a function called through multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797484/how-to-retrieve-multiple-values-returned-of-a-function-called-through-multiproce) . The answer made use of the function multiprocessing.Pool. I am looking for an answer that uses multiprocessing.Process.

Comment: Does it work if my_func just returns `x+y` rather than a tuple? My guess is that it doesn't and the issue is probably unrelated to my_func returning a tuple.

Comment: Ah, I suspect your issue is that return_dict is a dict, but your subprocesses are doing `return_dict[procnum_1][procnum_2]`. This will result in an error because `return_dict[procnum_1]` is not itself a dictionary.

Comment: Just checked and the code doesn't work even if my_func just returns x+y. Maybe this has something to do with the func taking in two arguments as well?

Comment: Oh so should I make return_dict a dictionary of a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def worker(procnum_1, procnum_2, x, y, return_dict):
    print("procnum_1: "+str(procnum_1)+", procnum_2: "+str(procnum_2))
    if procnum_1 not in return_dict:
        return_dict[procnum_1] = {}
    return_dict[procnum_1][procnum_2] = my_func(x[procnum_1],y[procnum_2])
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The code is now giving me [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] (all empty)